# How to auto-sequence cell reference when using quotation marks

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to copy a formula through an entire column on Google Sheets, but the formula is using the INDIRECT function, which has the cell reference in ""

=INDIRECT("'Raw Data'!N7")

This means the cell reference is being treated like a string and the same value is being copied

I tried using char(34) in the formula but that did not work

=INDIRECT(char(34)&'Raw Data'!N7&char(34))

How can I paste this formula through the column to reference the correct cells?

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` is not supported in `ARRAYFORMULA`

try:

```
={'Raw Data'!N7:N}
```

if you rly need indirect try:

```
=INDIRECT("Raw Data!N7:N")
```

or you can also do it the long way:

```
=INDIRECT("Raw Data!"&ADDRESS(7, 14, 4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 14, 4), 1, ))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first way but getting an error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in (last cell)"
I can see the formula expanding to N8, N9, etc. but any idea why this error is popping up?

Comment: @Duke_Si1ver arrays work like that. they need to roll out and for that they need space (empty cells). the error you got just indicates that array/range cant be rolled out because there is no space where to. if you put this formula into N7 make sure range N8:N is totally empty. only then every row will be automatically processed from the top cell (N7). in other words - do not drag down formula in N7 downwards

Comment: You sir, are a life-saver. Thank you so much